# Need help with Windows batch script

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I have a hundred text files to which I would like to insert the numbers **1** to **100** at the end of each. the script below will add "some text here" to every file in a directory where the bat script is saved and executed.

```
FOR %%i IN (*.txt) DO echo some text here>> %%i
```

Now, I want numbers 1-100 inserted into the said 100 text files instead of "some text here".

What is the correct script in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at `for /?`

> FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end)
>   DO command [command-parameters]
>
> ```
> The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
> So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
> generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
> ```

Comment: can you write a script to do exactly as i described?

Comment: instead of `echo some text here`, you insert the `for loop` and inside this for loop, you `echo number >> %%i`.  `number` is your `%variable`. That's not too hard to do, is it?

Comment: Well, yeah, it is hard to do. OP wanted a solution that would scale by number of *txt files in the directory. His solution was close but failed to account for delayed variable expansion.  You solution would require first counting the number of matching files and then setting the for loop based on that.

Comment: Well, it seems like i mis-read what he wants then. I thought he simply want numbers 1 to 100 into each text file, not one number for each.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set count=0
FOR %%i IN (*.txt) DO (
  set /A count = !count! + 1
  echo !count! %%i 
  echo !count! >> %%i
)
```

The first echo prints the file names & the counter numbers that will be appended to each.

Comment: hello, thanks for your response but it does not work correctly. instead of appending the counter numbers to each of my text files, it creates a file named "i" that contains the counter numbers 1-100.

Comment: The last line was supposed to have two percent signs.  Corrected now.

Comment: never mind. it works perfectly now. you just forgot one %. :)

Comment: Yup. sorry about that!  Bit of a debate going on here about what it was you were looking for.  Please settle it by accepting/voting an answer if you got what you were looking for.

Comment: @Joey and @T.Rob Some of my files have exclamation point in their filenames. what happens is the script creates files without exclamation points and inserts the "counter numbers" there (e.g. i have a file called Dance!.txt, it creates Dance.txt. what should i do to prevent this?